# Water meter still spinning even after shutting off water to house?

Tags: water, toilet, service

Our water meter is continuously spinning even after shutting off all the water to the house. We do have 2 different toilets that run about 4 times an hour on their own. I was wondering if the spinning meter could be that, or if it's definitely something else after shutting off house water? I would GREATLY appreciate any advice you may have as we are currently trying to sell and have absolutely no money for major repairs, thank you so much!

Comment: Why don't you fix your toilets? The parts to fix that problem are under $10.

Comment: Yeah, you're just flushing away $.

Answer (score 2):

I had a rental house a number of years ago that I bought and when I bought it there was a leak in the pipe between the meter and the house and it wasn't disclosed.

You should have a shutoff valve on the house, if it's functional, turn it off and see if the meter stops. If it doesn't stop you've got a leak between the meter and the house.

I also agree with Harper, fixing toilets is cheap and easy and will save on your water bill.